# Wire / terminal connections

Tags: power, connector, wire, terminal

I have this power jack socket. I would like to connect wires to the terminals permanently and to have a stable connection. I searched for a connector that would fit with the terminals of the power socket but couldn’t find one. Is there a wire connector I could buy or what method would you suggest for connecting wires to the terminals?

[image: power jack socket]
[link to the power jack socket I have](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ERPCV1Y)

Comment: Solder wires on the terminals

Comment: You can also use [2.8mm Crimp Terminal Female Spade Connector](https://goo.gl/dn8s6e)

Answer (score 1):

Those terminals look like they are intended for soldering.  There won't be any other type of connector.

So wire, solder and soldering iron required.

Answer (score 0):

You should wire the terminals as shown below. Two of the three pins will be shorted when unplugged. When plugged in, one of the two pins will float and cause go to the battery while the other two remaining will connect to your plug. Soldering is your best bet to permanently connect the wires.

- Pin 1 is used for your positive voltage
- Pin 2 is used for ground.
- Pin 3 is an optional pin to connect another power source such as internal batteries that would disconnect when the plug is inserted.

[image: DC Power Connector Diagram]

[image: Connections]